# Problem when running multiple Gunicorn scripts using systemd

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I want to automatically run multiple gunicorn servers which is generally are flask servers whenever my system reboot or start and also in background

The problems

1. Even though I could run the gunicorn server when manually start system service, but it runs only the first server which mentioned below, and won't start next service subsequently
2. Whenever I do reboot or start the system, it won't start the service automatically

`Start.sh`

```
base_gunicorn=/X/Y/anaconda3/envs/msclone/bin/gunicorn

cd ${base_path}"/ms/some_service1/"
${base_gunicorn} -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 1 --log-file some_service1.log wsgi:app >/dev/null 2>&1 &

cd ${base_path}"/ms/some_service2/"

${base_gunicorn} -b 0.0.0.0:8001 -w 1 --log-file some_service2.log wsgi:app >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

`myservice.service`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/X/Y/start.sh
RestartSec=2
```

Comment: This really should be two separate service files. Biggest case for this if one of the processes dies now, systemd won't know that the service failed because of the other running processes and won't know to restart it.

Comment: @jordann but I want to do one service will start multiple gunicorn  server ..

Comment: You can do one service with multiple instances: https://www.stevenrombauts.be/2019/01/run-multiple-instances-of-the-same-systemd-unit/

Answer (score -1):

```
# gunicorn1.service
[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn1
User=gunicorn
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/X/Y/anaconda3/envs/ms/some_service1/
ExecStart=/X/Y/anaconda3/envs/msclone/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 1 wsgi:app
RestartSec=2
```

```
# gunicorn2.service
[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn2
User=gunicorn
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/X/Y/anaconda3/envs/ms/some_service2/
ExecStart=/X/Y/anaconda3/envs/msclone/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8001 -w 1 wsgi:app
RestartSec=2
```

Create socket units as appropriate, per the doco.  Place the `Wanted-By=` that allows these to be enabled/disabled in the `[install]` section of the socket units.  It's the *socket units* that need to be autostarted, not the service units — per the doco, again.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). "[If you have two services, define two services.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/two-services.html)".  *The `systemd` House of Horror*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#systemd

Comment: i want to run single system service to start multiple gunicorn server.